# Orbits of two-dimensional real upper-triangular matrices on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let G be the group $\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{pmatrix} :a,b,c \in \mathbb{R} \}$ and define the action $\pi$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $\pi_g(x) = gx, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^2$. How many orbits are there?

So what I thought is that $Orb( \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}) = \{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \}$ and $Orb( \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}) = \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \}$ (since any nonzero vector $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$ can be written as $g \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, where $g=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix}$ is upper triangular, so there are only the two aforementioned orbits. Is this correct? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G$ is not a group as written, because if $a = 0$ or $c = 0$ then the matrix does not have an inverse.

If you assume $a,c \neq 0$ then you should end up with more than two orbits under the action of $G$ on $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: I see. Then $Orb( \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} )$ gives all non-zero vectors whose y-coordinate is nonzero, so adding to the above orbits $Orb( \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} )$, which is the set of all nonzero vectors whose y-coordinate is zero should give me all the orbits, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right! If you think about the vector $\binom{1}{0}$ under the action of upper triangular matrices, then it should be easy to see why it lies in an orbit somewhere between just the zero vector and all of $\mathbb R^2$, even if you forget the detail about $a,c \neq 0$